# Import Excel File into Oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, import

I have an Excel file that I need to import into a (new) Oracle table.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help ?

http://oracleebusinesssuite.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/import-of-an-excel-or-any-other-file-external-data-into-oracle/

http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_excel_spreadsheet.htm

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (technically) way is to export the contents as a CSV and use SQL*Loader to import it into the table.  [This link](http://www-camden.rutgers.edu/help/Documentation/Oracle/server.815/a67792/ch05.htm) goes to the documentation for SQL*Loader, which will explain how to write a SQL*Loader control file.

If you need to automate the export to CSV this can be done through OLE automation or VBA code within the spreadsheet.  You could also use VBA ([shell](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/shell.htm)) to execute the SQL*Loader command if you want to provide a facility for the end-user to initiate the load.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sharewareconnection.com/import-table-from-excel-for-oracle.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's possible to set up an Excel file as an ODBC source, but don't ask me how to do that.

I generally just save the spreadsheet as CSV and import it using Oracle APEX's CSV import wizard.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform any validation or cross-referencing on the data, I suggest using an entity relationship manager like Talend, etc. You can write scripts to do things like this, but a tool can make this a bit less painful.